# plpgsql, variable inside query in function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I am new with plpgsql. I create new function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createObj(number integer)
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
BEGIN

END;
$$
```

I have problem that if I want to make query in the body of the function and use in the query the the number variable while in  the table their is a number the boolean is always true.

something like:

```
 Select * from objects O, where O.number=number...
```

so number is not the number of the function but the filed in the table.
Their is a way to implement this and dont change the variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your parameters with a prefix to distinguish them from columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createObj(in_number integer)
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    Select * from
    objects O
    where O.number = in_number...
END;

$$
```

Comment: thanks, I though that their is a way to take the original variable.. Thanks anyway .

Comment: @Alon . . . You can use `$1`.  I think it is just a good habit to use parameter and variable names that can't be confused with other things.